# Create a string array where the index “value” is a string

Tags: excel, vba

Already looked in the forum but was not able to find anything similar.

I would like to create a string array where the index “value” is a string.

For instance:

```
MyArray(“abc”)=1
MyArray(“def”)=2
MyArray(“ghi”)=3
```

Is there a way to do this in VBA or can I achieve the same in a different way?

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks... will look at that

Comment: [VBA Dictionary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dND4coLI_B8) ..

Answer (score 1):

### A Dictionary Introduction

**A Simple Example**

```
Sub DictIntroduction()

    Dim InitText As Variant, InitNumbers As Variant
    InitText = Array("abc", "def", "ghi")
    InitNumbers = Array(1, 2, 3)

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(InitText)
        dict.Add InitText(i), InitNumbers(i)
    Next

    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print Key, dict(Key)
    Next

    Debug.Print dict("abc")
    Debug.Print dict("def")
    Debug.Print dict("ghi")

End Sub
```

To find out more about the dictionary visit the following links:

[Excel VBA Dictionary - A Complete Guide (Article)](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

[Excel VBA Dictionary (YouTube Playlist)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7ScsebMq5uUgeV-r9gIAAvXtgIxURfHa)

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub main()
    Set myArray = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    myArray("abc") = 1
    myArray("def") = 2
    myArray("ghi") = 3
    
    Debug.Print myArray("abc")
    
    For Each tempKey In myArray
        Debug.Print tempKey, myArray(tempKey)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't clear what this adds to the answer which is already given. Also, the failure to declare the variables teaches bad VBA habits. It is fairly common on Stack Overflow that someone posts a VBA question that would have been unnecessary if the person who posted it had simply used `Option Explicit`.